# singular or plural? - "an additional five words" vs " additional five words"

Tags: articles, singular-vs-plural

Why do we need "an" in these sentences below?

- I run **an additional** three-tenths of a kilometer.
- I write **an additional** 5 words.

As an English learner, I would omit "an," because it's illogical for me. I see plural forms, so my first reaction is to omit the articles. I would say:

> - I run additional three-tenths of a kilometer.
> - I write additional 5 words.

Please explain me the differences between these sentences, because my all grammar knowledge has just fallen.

I found a semi-explanation [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/an-additional-a-further-two-months.1222517/), does it make any sense?

Comment: I think "an additional five words" treats those "five words" as a whole.

Comment: @Cardinal might be right. I guess you could then say _"I ran two additional 5 kilometres"_. You definitely need the article in your examples, but if you were to swap the number and the word "additional", or remove the number entirely (but keep a plural noun/unit) you would definitely remove the article.

Comment: Think of it as *I run an additional (distance of) three-tenths of a kilometer* and *I write an additional (amount of) five words*.

Comment: @Cardinal Does it change the meaning of the sentence? Or maybe it doesn't play a role, and I'm good with all these options?

Comment: I think using singular form, when referring to the amount of something, is more common. However, I think there wouldn't be any significant difference if you use the plural form.

Answer (score 2):

"**an** (additional)" treats whatever follows as a whole.

Compare:

> - I run **an additional** three-tenths of a kilometer.
> - I run **an additional** distance.

and

> - I write **an additional** 5 words.
> - I write **an additional** paragraph.

---

If you want to remove "an", you can use:

> - I run additional**ly** three-tenths of a kilometer.
> - I run three-tenths of a kilometer **more**.

or:

> - I write additional**ly** 5 words.
> - I write 5 words **more**.
> - I write 5 **more** words. (which is actually much better than previous)